# Wordpress plugins for membership?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to create a membership-basee website and I'm new to Wordpress so its been a headache trying to look for free plugins that can

- creates 3 levels of membership (non-members, members, and premium members)
- limit access to certain pages/functionality of the site to members/premium members
- Also can't find a good plugin for customizable registration form

Comment: This is very specific to WordPress and not programming-related; you should ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com (if the answer to your question doesn't already exist there, obviously)

Comment: I clicked the link and it said: Couldn't find worpdress.stackexchange.com
The Q&A site worpdress.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet.

Comment: worDPress not worPDress, sorry! I edited my comment accordingly (edit: the whole galaxy of SO and SE sites is in the footer)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Paid Memberships Pro, which is 100% open source, and available in the WordPress repository:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

Here is some code to use hooks in the plugin to add fields to checkout page. It takes a bit of php skill and programming:
https://gist.github.com/1389944

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a membership website with WordPress, the memberpress plugin is what you should know about. It allows you to restrict certain areas and even add membership tiers for your WordPress website. it is one of the best plugins available for membership websites, you can check out the memberpress website from this link

https://memberpress.com/myohoguy/home